# Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler #2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, bundler

I'm new to ruby on rails and working on a project on AWS cloud9. I went through other posts on stackoverflow but still couldn't find the solution to solve the error below. I have tried `bundle install`, `bundle update`, `git add Gemfile.lock`, none of them worked for me.

```
ec2-user:~/environment/saasapp (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 7991, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (6447/6447), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7991/7991), 48.09 MiB | 47.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 7991 (delta 1044), reused 7778 (delta 967)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find pg-0.18.4 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find pg-0.18.4 in any of the sources
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to radiant-tor-65852.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/radiant-tor-65852.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-tor-65852.git'
```

Here is the gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# Use Twitter Bootstrap library for front-end UI and layout
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'

# Use Font Awesome sass gem for adding icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.13'

# Use Hirb for better db display in console
gem 'hirb', '0.7.3'

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  # Use the PostgreSQL gem for heroku production servers
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: can you psot your gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the solution.

First, type this command line:

```
sudo yum install /usr/include/libpq-fe.h
```

Then:

```
bundle install --with production
```

Worked for me!